# Replace the C socket API in C++ on z/OS

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am including sys/socket.h, I still get compile time errors telling me that AF_INET is not defined. but still i am facing the issues getting the C sockets API to work properly in C++. please help me...

Comment: Did you include `<netinet/in.h>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the *z/OS UNIX System Services sockets* section in the *z/OS* XL **C/C++** Programming Guide. Make sure you're including the necessary header files and using the appropriate #defines.